# Some classess of my CSS file are not rendering into Django templates (most classess render without problems)

Tags: html, css, django, sass, bower

I'm starting with Django, I've been throught this several hours, please help me!

on my *.html file I have this code (and more):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

and since I added that static file, my page has style.. but some classes don't render, for example this div:

```
<div class="nav-profile-image">
```

If I delete the class .nav-profile-image from style.css, the page still the same, that image has no container, it's very strange.

I uploaded all the app on branch "problems": https://github.com/franchodl/robohome/tree/problems

view trying to render: home

url for home: http://127.0.0.1:8000/propietario/

template: ./own/templates/own/home.html

static files: ./static

Maybe the problem it's another thing, not the css, i downloaded the frontend from:

https://github.com/BootstrapDash/PurpleAdmin-Free-Admin-Template

When I open it from index.html, the page works good, the problem is from Django.

Any ideas??? I have no idea what else to check.

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

finally I solve my own problem:

On my static folder, i had two files:

```
x/package.json
y/bower.json
```

on the folder "x" it was a Front-End package developed with Gulp, and that json has the dependencies for the correspondent css/scss/js files, that can be downloaded automatically with:

```
npm install
```

and on folder "y", is a json file for bower dependencies, build with:

```
npm install --save bower-json
```

Wish you luck! and happy coding :D